# Build image classification library using weka

Tags: java, c#, weka, imagej

I am new to Weka and have a Project in which I have to give an image a class after processing it. A class is like a type of image. Like if it's tiger image after processing the image I have to say it's tiger class in animals. After some research I found that I have to build image library and all like animal library. But don't know how to do any of it. I have to use Weka, C# to do it. Any help would be great.

**edit**: 
I got to know that I have to first extract features from image and use that in weka so.

Comment: Do the "Advanced data mining with weka MOOC", they have a lecture on classifiying images into cars-trains-aircraft.

Comment: thank you and I have to first extract the features Know ?

Answer (score 2):

In ImageJ (Java) there exists an image classification plugin based on WEKA:

http://imagej.net/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation

The Java source code can be found here and maybe of help:

https://github.com/fiji/Trainable_Segmentation/